# Using AutoMapper with EF6 DbFirst and Stored Procedure (complex types)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework 6 DBFirst, MVC5 and AutoMapper.

I have 2 tables, Customers and CustomerContacts
For each class I have in Entity Framework EDMX (auto-generated) I have a Model class with the exact same properties. i.e. Customer => Model.Customer, CustomerContact => Model.CustomerContact. This is why I use AutoMapper.

Question 1: Since my Customer_Get stored procedure returns an auto-generated complex type (Customer_Get_Result) would most people make an additional model class for this also? (Model.Customer_Get_Result.cs) Or are all of the properties supposed to get combined adding everything to Model.Customer?

Question 2: Is the way I am handling mapping for Customer Contacts below correct? Mostly every property in Model.Customer is exactly the same as the AutoGenerated EF6 DBFirst file except for this which I placed in Model.Customer:

```
public List<CustomerContact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

In the end I want to be able to use Customer.Contacts to automatically get a list of all that Customer's contacts

In my AutoMapper I am trying to do something like this but don't think this is correct:

```
    CreateMap<Customer, Model.Customer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerContact));

    //map for customer getlist stored proc which will be returning several fields
    //such as TotalCount, RowNumber, fields from a bunch of other tables
    CreateMap<Customer_Get_Result, Model.Customer>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a stored procedure's complex type (Customer_Get_Result) would most
>   people make an additional model class for this also?

If it is exactly same properties as Customer, then I probably wouldn't create a model just for it, and just map it to the existing model.

Although it depends on what you are doing with this Model class, and whether the use case for the data mapped from the entity is any different than the data mapped from the stored procedure. Model's are just a fancy term for POCO.  Models are often one of two things.  A simplification of the entity, that is closer to a POCO than the EF entity is; such as DTO's you might use between your business layer and database layer.  Or it is a specialization for a particular context, such as a ViewModel that has only properties needed for a particular view and often includes things like data annotations that are UI specific.

It depends alot on how your application is layered and what part of the application is retrieving data, and what it plans to do with that data.  That said, I'd probably start with just using the same Model and see if I feel a need to rafactor later(but you'll still need 2 mappings, one from SP_Complex_Type -> Model, and one Entity -> Model).

Looks like your DB/EF model only has a single related contact from `Customer.CustomerContact`, but your model has a one-to-many relationship `Model.Customer.Contacts`. I'm basing this only on the plurality of the property name since you didn't give us any declarations of your entity. Either way **there's a mismatch on the relationship your EF entity supports versus the relationship your Model supports**.  There's alot of different things you can do here with AutoMapper, but you can't make that decision until you figure why one has a list of related contacts, and the other only has a single related contact.

```
CreateMap<Customer, Model.Customer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerContact));
```

When mapping a list to a list, and the properties are named differently, then the above is exactly what you would do.  Additionally if the types in each list are different, then you need to make sure your previously declared a map for those types as well.  For example, if you are going from `List<CustomerContactEntity>` to `List<CustomerContactModel>` then you need to have already done a `CreateMap<CustomerContactEntity,CustomerContactModel>` to tell AutoMapper it can convert these types.  This way as it encounters each item in the list, it will see that it has a mapping for that child type.

Comment: Thank you very much for the descriptive answer, it cleared a few things up. I am not sure what you mean my table name is CustomerContact and I am not sure why Entity Framework didn't pluralize the Navigation property it created based on the relationship I created in SQLServer to be CustomerContacts rather then CustomerContact, but for now lets just assume it is a one-to-many with a Navigation property. My project structure is the following: .Web(MVC5), .Business(Services, RepoInterfaces, ServiceInterfaces, Logic), .Data(Strictly EF6 EDMX, Repositories), .Model(POCO classes).

Comment: Everything references the Model, Data references Business, Web references Business. Normally in a simple MVC5 app I would use DBFirst without the POCO concept and just be able to use Customer.Contacts in linq. With this enhanced project structure and addition of POCO classes/AutoMapper it confuses me a bit when it comes to one-to-many relationships and mappings.

Comment: @user2272527 I've added to the answer.  Mapping a property List<A> to another property of type List<B> requires that you've defined a mapping from A -> B seperately.  Nothing else usually is required, as AutoMapper maintains a list of the mappings you've created, so when it tries to map List<A> -> List<B> it will use your mapping for each item to convert A -> B

Comment: So then how would you recommend going about displaying Customer Contacts in my Customer/details.cshtml. I have access to my Customer's basic info in my razor page because it is the primary model of the page. Will it be as simple as looping through Customer.Contacts in razor?

Comment: @user2272527 Should be, as long as you made sure you populated the Contacts when running your EF query using "eager loading" such as `.Include(c=>c.CustomerContact)`

Comment: I am a bit confused how that will work because in my Details(int? id) ActionResult I am doing Model.Customer cust = custService.GetCustomerByID(id) return view(cust). So before passing it to the view can I do the .Include you just told me about or is that only for lists. Sometimes I wonder if it would be better to just add something like GetCustomerContacts(int id) to my CustomerService and then send multiple lists to my view.

Comment: @user2272527 `.Include` is a method you can call on an EF query.  So it will need to be inside GetCustomerByID where you make the EF query.  Of course you may not always want the child items, so GetCustomerByID might take an `, bool includeContacts)` parameter, or instead some people use a repository pattern where their database layer function don't return entities, but instead returns IQueryable so that you can add additional calls like `.Include` on the return, that way the caller decides what additional criteria and data they want.